# How do I test if my betas form a co-integrated vector?

Tags: regression, cointegration, pca

I have identified a model using principal component regression where $Y_t$ is explained by 4 factors such as:

$$Y_t = \beta_1 X_{1t} + \beta_2 X_{2t} + \beta_3 X_{3t} + \beta_4 X_{4t} + \epsilon_t$$

Where: $Y, X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$ are $\text{I(1)}$ variables.

If I check that $\epsilon_t$ is stationary, can I assume that the variables are co-integrated and hence there was no spurious regression in my principal component regression?

Comment: As this is a question about statistics/econometrics rather than finance, it should be moved to [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Quantitative Finance SE works](https://quant.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

If a regression of an integrated variable on one or more integrated variables yields a stationary residual, the variables are cointegrated. This is a special case of the definition of cointegration.

Make sure to use appropriate null distribution and corresponding critical values when testing for absence of a unit root in $\epsilon_t$. Since $\epsilon_t$ is a residual rather than raw data, it is more likely to appear stationary by construction; that is why you need critical values as in Engle & Granger's procedure rather than the regular critical values of an augmented Dickey-Fuller (ADF) test.